# Flying to Wien, Austria from Denmark, legal with only temporary passport?

Tags: passports, paperwork, denmark, austria, danish-citizens

I will be traveling to Wien, Austria at the end of next month, taking a flight from Denmark. Unfortunately, my local municipality are unable to provide me with a new passport in time (my old one had expired), and will provide me with a temporary one (it's basically just a piece of printed paper).

I am a Danish citizen, in case it's relevant.

My question is:
Will I be able to travel to Wien, using only the temporary passport? I can of course bring my old passport and other forms of identification, but I want to be sure I wont be denied entry and that I have all my bases covered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Denmark-Austria is effectively a domestic route; no border control is carried out, only an ID check by bag drop if you check in luggage, to confirm that you're the ticket holder.

Furthermore, under the freedom of movement **you have the right to be in Austria no matter what**, and as the emergency passport proves nationality, you'll be fine in case police stops you while you're in Vienna (which has never happened to me, and I've been there a couple of times).

To be honest with you, unless flying with a low-cost airline, the emergency passport is a waste of money. If you've got any other photo ID (such as a driving licence), staff at bag drop at Kastrup and Vienna will accept it, and you'll rarely be asked for anything but your boarding pass at the gate.

Comment: The airline might have an issue, especially an LCC.

Comment: @JonathanReez Hence my last paragraph. But if you mean they might have an issue with an emergency passport, then no, because the most even the strictest airline can ever require for EU citizens flying within Schengen (or the rest of the EU for that matter) is a document proving nationality: namely a passport, emergency passport or national ID card.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all that info.  I got the temporary passport free of charge, as I already paid to have my current passport renewed.

Comment: @DionS.Jensen Strålende! Btw, if this answer satisfies you, please upvote it as well

Comment: @Crazydre would love to upvote, but sadly it only thanks me for my feedback :P I need 15 rep here for the vote to be recorded and displayed.

Comment: @DionS.Jensen You now have the rep to be able to upvote ;)

Comment: @JonathanReez I have seen people travelling with Romanian and Italian national ID card on low-cost carriers such as Ryanair or WizzAir lots of times. Are you aware of any cases when EU national ID cards were not accepted? (I myself have never travelled with national ID only)

Comment: @Szabolcs OP is asking about a temporary passport of some sort

Comment: @Szabolcs No airline in Europe has any specific policy not to accept national IDs. Instead, check-in staff is supposed to rely on the Timatic database to determine what documents are required. Once at Zurich, however, the gate agent (Swissport) nonchalantly tried to turn be away from an Airberlin flight to Pristina (Kosovo) when I showed my Swedish ID Card. Only when I told the hag four times to LOOK IN THE SYSTEM (no, I didn't shout, but got really irritated the third time) was I let onboard. So that kind of laziness is an issue for those not familiar with Timatic

Comment: @Crazydre "no matter what" is incorrect. The directive explicitly conditions the right on the possession of a valid travel document.  (Plus there are the exceptions for public health, safety, and policy.)

Comment: @phoog Any EU citizen has freedom of movement (though there are indeed the exceptions you mention), only some countries require you to be able to identify yourself and prove your nationality, whether local or foreign. Austria isn't one of those.

Comment: @Crazydre nobody can exercise a right without showing that they're qualified to do so.  So you have to be able to prove your nationality.  That implies identifying yourself. The right laid out by the directive allows countries to require a valid passport or national ID card even if some countries' national law allows people to prove their nationality by other means.

Comment: @phoog The right is absolute, not conditional on presenting a travel document. What can happen is you get fined for not holding a document **if** the member state requires it according to national law (such requirements apply to locals as well), but Austria doesn't have such a law

Comment: @Crazydre the text "Member States shall grant Union citizens leave to enter their territory with a valid identity card or passport" describes a right that can be conditioned on presenting one of the two named documents.  The right to remain for up to three months may similarly be conditioned on having such a document.

Answer (score -1):

According to Schiphol, you need a passport or European identity card to get through security even on flights between Schengen countries.

While they don't generally check them, spot checks can happen (and of course you are legally required to carry one with you at all times anyway, especially when abroad).

They also state that an emergency passport counts as a passport, and will be issued (though that's specific to the Dutch emergency passport) if you can show that you could not delay your travel until a normal passport can be issued instead (not relevant to you as you already have the emergency passport).

They go on to state that it is valid only in combination with some other form of government ID (so most likely a driver's license or European ID card), that it's not accepted by all countries, and only valid for the trip it was issued for.

So yes, the emergency passport should suffice.

https://www.schiphol.nl/en/page/passport-issues/

Comment: I'm not sure what relevant Schiphol's security procedures have for this question -- the OP is neither flying to nor from AMS, and even if he were connecting there, intra-Schengen connections in AMS do not pass through security.

Comment: "it is valid only in combination with some other form of government ID" Doesn't apply to the Danish emergency passport, though it does apply to the German "Reiseausweis als Passersatz", which, outside of Germany, is to be combined with an expired passport or (if accepted) ID card, or in Schengen and some other countries (like Serbia and the UK), a valid driving licence

Comment: I flew from the main terminal in Schipol to TXL two weeks ago. I neither showed my boarding pass (didn't have a paper one) nor any form of ID anywhere in the airport at all, including security. I took out my German ID card at boarding, but they ignored it completely.

Comment: @simbabque So not even the boarding pass was checked? Damn! Even within Schengen, I always have to show that (but never any ID except going from Poznan to Skavsta on Wizz)

Comment: @Crazydre they checked the boarding pass at boarding, but not at security. I had it as a PDF on my phone, and they didn't want me to turn it on at all. They just asked me to put the phone outside of my backpack when I was stuffing it in with my wallet so no-one would be able to grab it from the tray.

Comment: @Crazydre I have gone through several flights within the EU recently (all either departing from or terminating in Denmark) without ever showing any kind of document to any human being anywhere. My boarding pass (in Wallet on my phone) was scanned by an automated barcode reader before entering security and again when boarding, but no human interaction took place anywhere.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yup, aware of those gates